# JQuery по нажатию кнопок функция инкрементно срабатывает

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

Создаю в js таблицу, где в одной из колонок в каждой строке создаю кнопки.

```html
<input class="buttons" value="Delete" onclick="delRowOfTable();" type="button">
```

Эти кнопки по нажатию, должны получить номер строки в которой они находятся:

```js
function delRowOfTable() {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr').one( 'click',function(){
      alert(this.rowIndex+1);
    });
  });
}
```

Когда нажимаю одну из кнопок, всё срабатывает правильно и выдаёт правильный результат. Но когда нажимаю другую кнопку функция срабатывает два раза, т.е. алерт вылазит 2 раза, нажимаю 3ю кнопку - алерт вылазит 3 раза и т.д.
Как это пофиксить?

Добавил это в код, теперь всё отрабатывает по одному разу, вроде всё ок

```js
 $( 'tr').unbind( "click" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обработчик событий нужно повесить только один раз, сразу после загрузки

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr line_number=1>
    <td>
      <input class="buttons delbutton" value="Delete" type="button">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr line_number=2>
    <td>
      <input class="buttons delbutton" value="Delete" type="button">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr line_number=3>
    <td>
      <input class="buttons delbutton" value="Delete" type="button">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delbutton').on('click', delRowOfTable);
  });

   function delRowOfTable() {
     alert( $(this).parent().parent().index());
   }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Poul_WWJD/g74fytqw